# What is the formula for seasonal ARIMA model (2,1,2) (0,0,1)[4] w/ drift?

Tags: r, time-series, arima

```
Model: ARIMA(2,1,2)(0,0,1)[4] w/ drift 

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2     ma1     ma2    sma1  constant
      -0.7644  -0.7437  0.4964  0.9233  0.6741  3335.837
s.e.   0.0690   0.0608  0.0362  0.0393  0.0713  1246.015

sigma^2 estimated as 18215276:  log likelihood=-1787.95
AIC=3589.9   AICc=3590.54   BIC=3612.37
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are [dozens of posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arima+equation) like this on Cross Validated, and many have been answered. Yours is quite likely a duplicate. Have you tried looking at them?

Comment: @RichardHardy I have looked but have not found one with a seasonal component answered.

Comment: @Hunter, I have seen dozens with a seasonal component (yes, they are there), but I wonder if any of them included drift.